# Performance comparison of Dictionaries

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I'm interested in performance values (big-O analysis) of Lookup and Insert operation for .Net Dictionaries (generic or not): HashTable, SortedList, StringDictionary, ListDictionary, HybridDictionary, NameValueCollection, SortedList < T, U >, Dictionary < T,U >

Link to a web page with the answer works for me too.

Comment: Why are you even looking at non-generic collections, rather than those in `System.Collections.Generic`? Is there any particular reason?

Comment: I'm interested in generics too.

Answer (score 2):

It is documented on MSDN, see for instance the Remarks on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.add.aspx).